# How do I redirect back to calling app using ios custom URL scheme?

Tags: ios

I have an app in which i want to open some already installed games on device.
For example I can open "Temple Run" using it's custom URL "templerun:/". Is there any way though to come back to my app from "Temple Run" which has custom URL suppose "testapp:/"?

Are there any other ways to achieve this, like using web view or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because other apps don't know and implement your app scheme. iOS doesn't supply such API by now.

[x-callback-url](http://x-callback-url.com/) is something match your want, appA open appB by scheme and appB callback-open appA. But this protocol is not official support by iOS.

Comment: is there any other solution to do this? basically i just want to launch a game from my app and return back to my app

Comment: now i have source code of both the apps, and both apps have custom URL. i can launch app B from app A but how can i get back to app A onclick of "home" button

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done .But you can use a webview inside app to show the webpage and do the rest

```
NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Or just go for some call back uri API method .